# How get data when send in data-type json?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

*Good day.*

***Code:***

```
$("#user-search_input").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
      var form_data=$("#user-search_input").val();
      $.ajax({
        url: "./AutoCompliteFind/",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:{term: form_data},
        success: function(data) {
        //alert(data);

        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

*Tell me please how me get value parameter **term** on page **./AutoCompliteFind/** ?*

*P.S.: language - PHP*

*P.P.S.: If i use `var_dump($_POST)` i get `array(0) { }`.*

Comment: Thats server side,.....youll have to post your code for that page/function....what language? PHP? Ruby? ASP?

Comment: Have you checked your browser console's network tab to see if the request is being made, and you have POST arguments being sent?

Comment: If you make an AJAX call inside the source function, the source function returns before your ajax call is done. Did you check the jqueryui docs? Read my reply!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo $_GET['term'];
?>
```

BTW, if you specify a string in the source attribute, you'll get an ajax call to that file:

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
  source: "search.php",
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( ui.item ?
    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
  }
});
```

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte If i use `var_dump($_POST)` i get `array(0) { }`.

Comment: As far as I know, .autocomplete() sends a get var (yoururl.com?term=hello)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your server-side programming language, but in general,
Something like this (PHP):

```
$term = $_POST["term"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$string = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: i get `term=%D0%B0%D0%BB` tell me please how get value term with decode json?

Answer (score 0):

use [json_decode() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert json in array. Eg:

```
$term = $_POST["term"];
$term = json_decode($term);
```

Comment: not  working. if i use `var_dump($_POST)` i get `array(0) { }`